# Multiply a string in Java

Tags: java, multiplication

I have a String which contains a number and I would like to multiply that number with **1.28**

Here is how the string is assigned

```
String PRICE = dataRecord.get( "PRICE" );
```

Comment: Use UPPERCASE convention only for constants (`final` variables). [Naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to obtain a numeric representation of the data and perform a multiplication on it. Since the example is "price", I'm assuming money is involved, and will therefore recommend a decimal type.

```
String price = "9.99";
BigDecimal priceDecimal = new BigDecimal( price );
BigDecimal total = priceDecimal.multiply( new BigDecimal( "1.28" ) );
System.out.println( total );
```

Comment: I get Class: BigDecimal not found in namespace, is there something I need to import?

Comment: [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: As @Brian mentioned, you probably also want to scale the result, if dealing with currency: `.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);`

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use a proper object with a double field type.

```
double price = dataRecord.price * 1.28;
```

Similar to @Rob's example which gives the same answer.  You decide which is simpler. ;)

```
double price = 9.99;
double total = price * 1.28;
System.out.printf("%.4f%n", total);
```

For money, I recommend using double with appropriate rounding.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want, is:

```
double price = dataRecord.getDouble( "PRICE" );
```

Assuming that dataRecord is a ResultSet object. In any way, It would be much much better to use BigDecimals, and, if PRICE is really stored in a String object, then I assume you did this because you know about the float-precision problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
String priceAsString = dataRecord.get( "PRICE" );

double priceAsInt = Double.valueOf(priceAsString).doubleValue();
double multipliedPrice = priceAsInt * 1.28;
```

If you don't need to convert it to a String after multiplying the value just remove the last line.

Comment: It is likely that the price won't be an integer. If you are going to convert a double to a String you should use some form of rounding, or you can see a rounding error.

Comment: Thank you about your feedback. You are absolutely right I will correct my answer. But with rounding error you mean a wrong rounded number of course, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a double in order to do the multiplication. Double.parseDouble() is a method you could use. I chose to wrap this in a try block in case the string is malformed and an error is thrown (if price is for some reason not a number - ex. 5.67b or 8..34).

```
String price = dataRecord.get( "PRICE" );
try {
    double p = Double.parseDouble(price);
    double result = p*1.28;
    System.out.println(result);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { // ERROR HANDLING
    System.out.println("Error parsing string: Price is not a number.");
}
```

For your reference, here is the documentation for parseDouble().

*public static double parseDouble(String s)
                          throws NumberFormatException*

Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

Comment: I suggest you round the answer to avoid rounding errors. e.g. printf("%.4f%n", result);

Comment: I also suggest that you print the actual exception, rather than discarding it otherwise, you are better off not handling it IMHO.

Comment: I handled the exception in my code in order to demonstrate to the person who asked the question that parseDouble() could potentially throw an error. It is up to them if they want to include the error handling or not. By the way, thanks for the tip about the rounding. Its a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math.  Use BigDecimal and **you need to set the scale on the result** to invoke rounding as most likely the scale will be bigger than what you want.

```
private static final BigDecimal MULT = new BigDecimal("1.28");

BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(dataRecord.get("PRICE"));
BigDecimal result = price.multiply(MULT).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: do the following
Double.ParseInt("Stringname"), will reutnr the double value
PLS give some credit if you like the answer